# Per user behavior based scoring in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We do understand the behavior of user by analyzing the tags he usually search for.
Now we need to give higher precedence for such tags for these users. I would like to know how we can achieve this using Elasticsearch in an elegant manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the best approach for this would be to

1. Analyse the behavior of the user
2. See which all keywords are of his interests
3. Maintain one document per user in another index which have all these keywords.
4. On the searches for that user , boost the occurrence of these keywords using [function_score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)
5. You can use terms filter inside boost function to achieve this.Add the boost function under functions in the function score query
6. In [terms filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_terms_lookup_twitter_example) , you can point to this users document and get the values dynamically
7. Use custom filter key so that the cache key constructed wont eat too much memory

In this approach , you can avoid lots of code paths in client code.